# Swift3: Populate UITableView with data from External database?

Tags: uitableview, swift3, nsurlsession

I am trying to load the UItable with some data from the external database. I am able to print the required data in the output panel but cant get the data on the tableview. How can I fix this?

Code:

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    //let myarray = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]



    var group = [Group]()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "http://www.myurl/myfile.php")

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url! as URL) { data, response, error in

            guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }

            print(NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))
        }

        task.resume()        
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        tableview.reloadData()
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //return myarray.count
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "groupCell", for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
       // cell.textLabel?.text = myarray[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tableview reload before receiving data. You need to reload table view after completing task.

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url! as URL) { data, response, error in

guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }

print(NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))

//Store into your array depend on response.
DispatchQueue.main.async() {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
} } task.resume()
```